# jQuery UI multiple dialog box contents jumping to the top

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, dialog

If you have multiple jQuery UI dialog boxes open on a page with enough content to force a scroll bar, clicking between dialogs causes the content of the one that was active to scroll to the top.

You can see this JSFiddle for an example (one box is behind the other): http://jsfiddle.net/kRAd4/
If you scroll them both down a little and then click from one box to the other you'll see it happen.

Is there any way to stop this?

Here is the code used on the JSFiddle site, it's simple:

HTML:

```
<div class="hi">Here<br />Is<br />A<br />Lot<br />Of<br />Text<br />Here<br />Is<br />A<br />Lot<br />Of<br />Text<br />Here<br />Is<br />A<br />Lot<br />Of<br />Text<br />Here<br />Is<br />A<br />Lot<br />Of<br />Text<br /></div>

<div class="hi">Here<br />Is<br />A<br />Lot<br />Of<br />Text<br />Here<br />Is<br />A<br />Lot<br />Of<br />Text<br />Here<br />Is<br />A<br />Lot<br />Of<br />Text<br />Here<br />Is<br />A<br />Lot<br />Of<br />Text<br /></div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(".hi").dialog({
    height: 200
});
```

UPDATE: 
I've tried adding `return false` to both the `mouseDown` and `focus` dialog options, and it made no difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same as Jared, I found that page that describes the bug you're having. It indeed talks about 1.9.2 working fine.

However, most of the time you do not roll back to previous versions on your project and I wanted to find a solution that keeps your current files. Therefore, I tested with some code presented there. I made an html page with your jQuery 2.0.2 version and jQuery UI 1.10.3 version.

The following solution fixes your problem, but I would use it only if you're sure there would be no other repercussions, or if you've tested it and are satisfied with the result.

I replaced the `_moveToTop` function in the jQuery UI file (the entire chunk) with this piece of code (you can find it in the same link [here](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/9166)):

```
_moveToTop: function( event, silent ) {
    var $parent = this.uiDialog.parent();
    var $elementsOnSameLevel = $parent.children();

    var heighestZIndex = 0;
    $.each($elementsOnSameLevel, function(index, element) {
        var zIndexOfElement = $(element).css('z-index');
        if (zIndexOfElement) {
            var zIndexOfElementAsNumber = parseInt(zIndexOfElement) || 0;
            if (zIndexOfElementAsNumber > heighestZIndex) {
                heighestZIndex = zIndexOfElementAsNumber;
            }
        }
    });
    var currentZIndex = this.uiDialog.css('z-index');

    var moved;
    if (currentZIndex >= heighestZIndex) {
        moved = false;
    } else {
        this.uiDialog.css('z-index', heighestZIndex + 1);
        moved = true;
    }

    if ( moved && !silent ) {
        this._trigger( "focus", event );
    }

    return moved;
},
```

Comment: Thanks, Omri - I will give that a try on Monday when I get back to work.

Comment: Sir, this worked fine, and I would like to buy you a drink, but that's probably not likely to happen. Please accept 100 e-points in its place.

Comment: And then I forgot to give them to you. Have done now!

Answer (score 3):

It looks like this is a bug in jquery UI 1.10, reported [here](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/9166).  In your fiddle, if you change jquery to 1.9.1 and jquery ui to 1.9.2, it works.  According to the bug report, it's fixed in 1.11 as well.

Comment: Thanks Jared - I searched everywhere but didn't use the right combination of words, obviously!